# The visualization interface shows incomplete results after executing cypher queries in Galaxybase

Tags: graph-databases

I have run into the problem when executing a cypher query against the database Galaxybase. The database can be downloaded [here](https://www.createlink.com/download).

Here is the query code I used.

```
    MATCH (p:Person)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(f:Person)
    WHERE p.name = 'Alice'
    RETURN p, f
```

The displayed results are about 100, the results are too long so I won't post them here. I checked the data and the results should be about 170. What causes incomplete results to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid Cypher query results return too much data, resulting in front-end can not be rendered or browser crash, the Galaxybase database visualization interface only show the first 100 records of the returned results of the Cypher query. If you need to get the full query result, please iterate through the driver to get the full result after executing cypher to the database.